# Relevant HTTP Status code on the Rest API

Tags: rest, http-status-codes

I have a scenario by passing invalid data in Path variable which is input to fetch the data from Database.As the provided data is not valid so it triggers "500 Internal Server Error" from the database as could not found the data.
and have customized HTTP Status as 404(NOT_FOUND) because data is not found.

Would like to understand,what can be the best HTTP Status code for this scenario other than 404?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is an application protocol, whose application domain is the transfer of documents over a network ([Jim Webber, 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s)).  The status codes we use in the response are metadata from the domain of document transfer -- which is to say, we care about what the message means, not why our implementation is sending it.

The information specific to your domain, which communicates the details of the problem to the client, belongs in the message-body of the response.  The status code is there so that generic components, that don't know the specifics of your domain, can "do the right thing" -- where the right thing is constrained by HTTP semantics.

[Michael Kropat published](https://www.codetinkerer.com/2015/12/04/choosing-an-http-status-code.html) flow charts that may help select the correct status code.  Alternatively, you can look through the [HTTP Status Code Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml), which has links to the standard that defines the semantics of each code.

Broadly speaking, if the problem is with the request, then we use some message from the `4xx` message class; problems in the request are client errors.  404 specifically directs the client's attention to the target-uri.

So if the request is bad because information encoded into a path segment is incorrect, then 404 is the correct choice, because it tells the client where to look for the problem.  The only reason that you would look elsewhere is if some other part of the 404 semantics were inappropriate for your circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

> Would like to understand what can be the best HTTP status code for this scenario other than `404`?

If you are looking for something other than [`404`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4), then you could look into the more generic [`400`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1). From the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231):

> [**6.5.1.  400 Bad Request**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1)
>
> The `400` (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

But bear in mind that the [`404`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4) status code itself is suitable for this situation. See the following quote from the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231):

> [**6.5.4.  404 Not Found**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4)
>
> The `404` (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists. [...]